# Calculate momentum as weighted average by recency

Tags: mysql, weighted-average, trend

I have a subscriptions table with an associated feed_id and creation timestamp. A feed has N subscriptions.

It's easy enough to show the most popular feeds using a `group` query to count the number of records with each feed_id. But I want to calculate momentum to show most trending feeds.

A simplified algorithm would be:

```
momentum of feed_id =
    10 * (count of subscriptions with created_at in past day)
  + 5 *  (count of subscriptions with created_at from 2-7 days ago)
  + 1 *  (count of subscriptions with created_at from 7-28 days ago)
```

How can something like this be done in a single (My)SQL query instead of doing it with 3 queries and programmatically summing the results?

Comment: Edit your question and show the data structure . . . sample data and desired results are really helpful in understanding the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this.  MySQL treats booleans as integers, with true being "1", so you can just sum the expression for time.

I am guessing it looks something like this:

```
select feedid,
       (10 * sum(createdat >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)) +
         5 * sum(createdat >= date_sub(now(), interval 7 day) and
                 createdat < date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)) +
         1 * sum(createdat >= date_sub(now(), interval 28 day) and
                 createdat < date_sub(now(), interval 7 day))
       ) as momentum
from subscriptions
group by feedid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 10*COUNT(IF(created_at >= CURDATE(), 1, 0)) +
       5*COUNT(IF(created_at BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), - INTERVAL 7 days) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), - INTERVAL 1 day), 1, 0) +
       1*COUNT(IF(created_at BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), - INTERVAL 28 days) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), - INTERVAL 8 day), 1, 0)
FROM ...
```

I'm not 100% sure I've caught the edge conditions (yesterday or 8 days ago) to get exactly the right count.  You'll want to test that.

If you're interested in 24-hour periods then just substitute `NOW()` for `CURDATE()` and everything will go to DATETIME.